# how to make a drawing buffer in java

Tags: java

I'm new to java. and I want to create a game like snake. How can I make a drawing buffer java, where I can draw all the images? Like the background images, the objects such as the snake, etc.

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you have to look at official tutorials [2D Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), tons of examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Catalog2D-Graphics-GUI.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `BufferedImage` if CPU-based drawing is good enough for you. Rendering using `BufferedImage` is pretty easy by utilizing the `Graphics2D` class.

However, if you need full graphics acceleration, then I would suggest looking into some OpenGl binding for java, like JOGL or LWGL, or maybe even Java3D. I'm not personally familiar with these technologies, but from what I understand, they are all pretty popular portals for game programming in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The exact term you are looking for is "canvas". 
Here is an example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawcanvaswithcolorandtext.htm

Comment: Thank you my friend. Like I can draw a 2D images in the canvas?

Comment: Yes. If you look a the example code you will see a method called paint that has a parameter of type Graphics. This method is called each frame and drawing code should go there. You use the Graphics object to draw things. For example Graphics has a method called "drawImage" that will draw an image.

Comment: @Artium: Is swing implicitly double-buffered? If not, I don't see how this answers the question, although it does provide a simple example of using `Graphics` objects.

Comment: @Ken You are correct, although OP did not asked about double buffering, it is important to mention it. Fortunately, this technique is easy to implement with canvas. Here is the first hit on google for this: http://www.ecst.csuchico.edu/~amk/classes/csciOOP/double-buffering.html